# Random sample with conditions in r with dbplyr

Tags: r, dbplyr

I have a dataframe where I have to select 5 people who have at least 3 rows. So the idea is that I have a random sample for every id at least 3 rows or more. The data looks like this:

`head(df)`

```
    id year sex education no_kids health_org satisf_org health_std
1 312 2004   1        NA       1          4          7  0.5670103
2 399 2000   0        12       1          4          8  0.5670103
3 399 2001   0        12       1          4          9  0.5670103
4 457 2000   0        18       0          3          8 -0.4639175
5 457 2002   0        18       0          3          7 -0.4639175
6 457 2004   0        18       0          2          4 -1.4948454
   satisf_std
1 -0.09090909
2  0.47727272
3  1.04545450
4  0.47727272
5 -0.09090909
6 -1.79545450
```

I already created a way to do this but the result was not good enough. It looks like this:

```
library(dplyr) 
sample_n_groups = function(grouped_df, size, replace = FALSE, weight=NULL) {
  grp_var <- grouped_df %>% 
    groups %>%
    unlist %>% 
    as.character
  random_grp <- grouped_df %>% 
    summarise() %>% 
    sample_n(size, replace, weight) %>% 
    mutate(unique_id = 1:NROW(.))
  grouped_df %>% 
    right_join(random_grp, by=grp_var) %>% 
    group_by_(grp_var) 
}
df_sample <- df %>%  filter(n() >= 3) %>% group_by(id) %>% sample_n_groups(5)
```

Has anyone a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3) %>%
  distinct(id) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 5) %>%
  #For older version of dplyr
  #sample_n(5)
  left_join(df, by = 'id') -> df_sample
```

Here we first keep rows for `id` which have at least 3 rows in them, select `distinct` `id`'s from them and sample 5 id's from them. Using `left_join` we then select all the rows for those `id`s.

Comment: I get this error message : "size` must be less or equal than 1 (size of data), set `replace` = TRUE to use sampling with replacement." Doesn`t make any sense why this error occurs. :/

Comment: Are you using `sample_n` or `slice_sample` ? Are you sure if you have more than 5 id's that have more than 3 rows in them? What does `df %>%  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3) %>% distinct(id) %>% nrow` return?